# What does it mean to estimate a VAR model?

Tags: time-series, estimation, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression

I am currently working on my undergrad dissertation and I need to use VAR modelling. I vaguely understand what VAR, AR and MA are. What I am failing to understand is what "**estimating a VAR**" actually means. What does it imply? Does it mean finding the coefficient values?

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 3):

VAR is vector autoregression, that is, an autoregression on a vector-valued time series. A $K$-variate VAR($p$) model consists of $K$ time series. In other words, it is a generalization of an autoregressive (AR) model to a multivariate setting. However, there are no moving average (MA) components there.

Estimating a VAR model means finding the coefficient values. A $K$-variate VAR($p$) model has a $K$-long vector of intercepts and $p$ square matrices of dimension $K\times K$ of autoregressive coefficients. All of these need to be estimated.

VAR models can be estimated applying ordinary least squares (OLS) to each of the $K$ model equations separately. For an unrestricted model, this is as good as feasible generalized least squares (feasible GLS, or FGLS). If the VAR model has some coefficient restrictions, FGLS will be asymptotically more efficient than equation-by-equation OLS. There are other estimation alternatives such as maximum likelihood estimation which may be preferable if the model errors are nonnormally distributed.